# Optimal way to "get dummies" or "one hot encoding" and group by X

Tags: python, pandas, lambda, group-by

I have this pandas dataframe:

[image]

And want to end with something like this:

[image]

I really wondering how to speed the process without having to create my own function and create "manually" each column like:

```
df['n_months_till_first_incident'] = df.apply (lambda row: some_function(row), axis=1)
```

Another question, for a ML project, what should be the best when there is no second incident? -1 or null? - in order to play with it (some charts).

Answer (score 0):

Sort by `MONTHS_TILL_INCIDENT` and use `groupby` follow by [`cumcount`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) to enumerate the incidents that, at this point, are already in order of occurrence. Then, use [`pivot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html) to reshape the dataframe moving the order of the incidents to columns and the quantity of months to values.

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('sample.csv', sep='\s+')
print(df)

df.sort_values('MONTHS_TILL_INCIDENT', inplace=True)

df['INCIDENT'] = df.groupby(['START_DATE']).cumcount()+1

df = df.pivot(index=['ID', 'START_DATE'], columns='INCIDENT', values='MONTHS_TILL_INCIDENT')

df.columns = [f'N_MONTHS_TILL_{c}º_INCIDENT' for c in df.columns]
df = df.reset_index()

print(df)
```

Output from *df*

```py
   ID START_DATE  N_MONTHS_TILL_1º_INCIDENT  N_MONTHS_TILL_2º_INCIDENT  N_MONTHS_TILL_3º_INCIDENT
0   1    20/1/21                        2.0                        5.0                       11.0
1   2     5/2/21                        3.0                        NaN                        NaN
```